# Failed to compile wxWidgets-2.9.2 on Kubuntu11.10(64bit) with '--with-opengl' flag

Tags: c++, opengl, wxwidgets

I tried to compile wxWidgets-2.9.2 with opengl support by calling

```
configure --with-opengl
```

But it failed when the configure script tried to locate the lib files of opengl

```
checking for GL/gl.h... yes
checking for GL/glu.h... yes
checking for -lGL... no
checking for -lMesaGL... no
configure: error: OpenGL libraries not available
```

However, I checked /usr/lib and found that there is libGL.so in that directory. Actually, before trying to compile wxWidgets-2.9.2, I had written several opengl programs and all were successfully compiled and run. Could someone help me to fix this?

---

This is actually a bug in the configure script, please see

```
http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/13375.
```

The solution is to download the latest codes from

```
http://svn.wxwidgets.org/svn/wx/wxWidgets/trunk/
```

Or you can select to overwrite only the configure,acinclude.m4 files.

Comment: Did `-lGL` work every time previously with no additional flags?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you tried installing the free implementation?

```
sudo apt-get install libglw1-mesa libglw1-mesa-dev
```

Are you running proprietary drivers from Nvidia or something? I think it messes around with the OpenGL environment while installing. Perhaps, it is worth trying to go back the the opensource ones if this is the case.

There is also a know issue [OpenGL libs not located by 'configure' in debian testing](http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/13375)

Comment: If it's not enough to compile, then use: `sudo apt-get install libglu1-mesa-dev freeglut3-dev mesa-common-dev`

Answer (score 5):

I also met the same problem when trying to compile wxWidgets3.1.0 --with-opengl on Debian Jessie x86_64. I tried

```
SEARCH_LIB="`echo "$SEARCH_INCLUDE" | sed s@include@$wx_cv_std_libpath@g` /usr/$
wx_cv_std_libpath /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu"
```

and

```
pkg-config --variable=libdir gl
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
```

and

```
sudo apt-get install libglw1-mesa libglw1-mesa-dev
```

but:

> OpenGL libraries not available

I then tried

```
sudo apt-get install glutg3-dev
```

but:

> glutg3-dev is not found.

So I searched for the alternative to glutg3-dev in Jessie and I tried

```
sudo apt-get install freeglut3-dev
```

then it worked!

Answer (score 4):

First of all check if opengl libs are installed! them --->
**we need to change Configure file on source!** check this link:
http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/13376

the same issues arise on ubuntu 12.04!

Answer (score 0):

Installing mesa didn't help for me, but installing `glutg3-dev` did the trick

```
sudo apt-get install glutg3-dev
```